# Combine 3D plots with different ranges into one

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

The following script generates two plots in a row, both of them controlled by Manipulate. I would like to combine them together in one.

The problem I don't know how to solve is that the plotting region in `Q` is different for the two plots, even though it is included in the range $Q \in [0,1]$.

```
Manipulate[Row[{
    Plot3D[{
            (1 - 2 Q - Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ]) (1 + Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ])
            }, {θ, 0.001, π/2 - 0.001}, {Q, 0, Min[((1 - Δ^2) Sin[2 θ]^2)/(2 (1 + (-1)^0 Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ])), -(-1)^0 Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ]]},
            AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large
    ],
    Plot3D[{
            (1 - Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ]) (1 - 2 Q + Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ])
            }, {θ, 0.001, π/2 - 0.001}, {Q, 0, Min[((1 - Δ^2) Sin[2 θ]^2)/(2 (1 + (-1)^1 Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ])), -(-1)^1 Sqrt[1 - Δ^2] Cos[2 θ]]},
            AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large
    ] 
}], {{Δ, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

PS The range in $\theta$ is $[0.001, \pi/2 -0.001] $ to prevent errors.

Comment: What is wrong with using `Show` to combine them and then use `PlotRange->All`? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLpTu.png)

Comment: Good job Nasser, post the answer. Thanks @Kuba for editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine the 2 plots, you can use Show. In addition, since Show takes its options from the first plot, you can override these by using `PlotRange->All` in the Show itself, at the end. Like this

```
Manipulate[
 Show[      
    Plot3D[...],
    Plot3D[...],
    PlotRange -> All
  ]
 , ....]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]